# 21-миллионый, 21-тысячный, 101-тысячный словами?

Tags: грамматика, числительные, орфография

Как будет правильно написать 21-миллионный, 21-тысячный и 101-тысячный словами?

Слова должны быть "двадцатиодн​**?**​миллионный", "двадцатиодн​**?**​тысячный" и "стоодн​**?**​тысячный" соответственно, но сомнения вызывает какая буква будет на месте знака вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
двадцатиодномиллионный
двадцатиоднотысячный
стооднотысячный
```

Во всех Ваших примерах проблема в единице. Как я понимаю, практически нереально найти какое-нибудь строгое правило на этот счет, но в одном [источнике](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5#441), на мой взгляд, заслуживающем доверия, пишут:

> Большинство таких прилагательных образуется от формы родительного
>   падежа количественных числительных. *Сто* и *девяносто* (а также *много*)
>   выступают в форме именительного падежа: *столетний*,
>   *девяностодвухлетний*, *многоцелевой*. Первая часть сложных
>   прилагательных, образованных от *один*, имеет вид *одно-*: *однопролётный*,
>   *односоставный*.
>   <…>

---

Так что:

```
двухтысячный
двадцатипятитысячный
```

(от родительного падежа *двух*, *двадцатипяти*).

Но:

```
стотысячный
```

(от именительного падежа *сто*)

и:

```
однотысячный
```

(от *одно-*).

Comment: Много is adverb, it has no cases.

Answer (score 4):

Судя по всему - двадцатиодномиллионный.

Comment: Я вопрос обновил

Comment: Двадцатиоднотысячный соответственно

Comment: Там точно "о" в части "одно" везде?

Comment: @hazzik Конечно, соединительная гласная только «о» и «е» бывает.

Comment: @kirelagin а что вы скажите про "и"? между "двадцат" и "одно"? Или про "и" в "двадцатипятитысячный"?

Comment: @hazzik Да, действительно, тут, видимо, дело не в соединительных гласных… По всей видимости, общее праило такое: надо брать родительный падеж и склеивать непосредственно, за исключением «сто-», «девяносто-» и «одно-».

Comment: @kirelagin где про это исключение можно прочитать?

Comment: @hazzik Насколько я понимаю, найти какие-нибудь строгие правила на этот счет практически нереально. Можно [вот здесь](http://rusgram.ru/Числительное#441) посмотреть (третий абзац).